# Using "less than or equal" in IF statement in NeoOffice Calc 

Tags: mac, spreadsheet, neooffice

How would I call a "less than or equal" function in an if statement in Mac NeoOffice Calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume it's just `<=`, for example

```
=IF(A5 <= 16, "yes", "no")
```